# Nested array filter with return only unique elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
{
  list: [
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "RUS",
          "desc": "Russian"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "RUS",
          "desc": "Russian"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "IND",
          "desc": "Indian"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "USA",
          "desc": "American"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "AUS",
          "desc": "Australian"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "JPN",
          "desc": "Japan"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "RUS",
          "desc": "Russian"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "IND",
          "desc": "Indian"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [
        {
          "code": "RUS",
          "desc": "Russian"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array LanguageCodes[
  {
    "code": "RUS",
    "desc": "Russian"
  },
  {
    "code": "IND",
    "desc": "Indian"
  },
  {
    "code": "USA",
    "desc": "American"
  },
  {
    "code": "AUS",
    "desc": "Australian"
  },
  {
    "code": "JPN",
    "desc": "Japan"
  }
]
```

I have one nested array which represents the language codes.

list Array contains the various object with the languageCodes displayed into the code snippet. And languageCodes array contains the code and desc which are also shown into the snippet.
So here my requirement is to filter the array and output would be like unique languageCodes array as shown in OUTPUT.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: your langages code arrays always have one element ?

Comment: Amazing, there's at least 6 unique ways of doing this, and you tried absolutely nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and pull out `code` and `desc` for unique values.

```js
var data = { list: [{ distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "RUS", desc: "Russian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "RUS", desc: "Russian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "IND", desc: "Indian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "USA", desc: "American" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "AUS", desc: "Australian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "JPN", desc: "Japan" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "RUS", desc: "Russian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "IND", desc: "Indian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "RUS", desc: "Russian" }] }] },
    result = Array.from(data.list
        .reduce(
            (m, { languageCodes: { 0: { code, desc } } }) => m.set(code, { code, desc }),
            new Map
        )
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) combined with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) and [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...of)

```js
const obj = {
  list: [{
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "RUS",
        "desc": "Russian"
      }]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "RUS",
        "desc": "Russian"
      }]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "IND",
        "desc": "Indian"
      }]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "USA",
        "desc": "American"
      }]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "AUS",
        "desc": "Australian"
      }]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "JPN",
        "desc": "Japan"
      }]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "RUS",
        "desc": "Russian"
      }]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "IND",
        "desc": "Indian"
      }]
    },
    {
      "distance": 1.87,
      "age": "",
      languageCodes: [{
        "code": "RUS",
        "desc": "Russian"
      }]
    }
  ]
};
const output = obj.list.reduce((acc, element) => {
  for (let lang of element.languageCodes) {

    if (!acc.find(l => l.code == lang.code)) {
      acc.push(lang);
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log("output", output);
```

Comment: probably because a) you aren't one of the cool kids and didn't make a runnable snippet (tongue in cheek comment), and b) ... what is `list`? it's a property of an object, so it wont work like that :p

Comment: `{ list: ..... }` list is a PROPERTY of an object ... so `list.reduce` wont work :p - I didn't downvote, I think your answer is one of the more readable ones

Comment: of course it works ! const a = { list : [] }. in this case  : a.list.reduce will totaly work...

Comment: exactly, but `list.reduce` would not, as there is no var called list ... `a.list.reduce` vs `list.reduce` ... if you think they are the same, then you need to check again

Comment: I know what the intent of your code is, but think of the OP - of the 6 and growing unique ways of solving this, he tried exactly NONE, so you got to think down to his level, i.e. he knows nothing

Comment: you've pulled out list property from his code and made it a variable - this OP NEVER attempts to write code for his problems, so would look at your code and think, well, that's not my object :p

Comment: Look at the edit I made - see how now `obj` is the same object as in the question :p as I said, **I** understand what you did, this OP wouldn't have a clue

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` and `filter`:

```js
const myObj = {list: [{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "RUS","desc": "Russian"}]},{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "RUS","desc": "Russian"}]},{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "IND","desc": "Indian"}]},{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "USA","desc": "American"}]},{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "AUS","desc": "Australian"}]},{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "JPN", "desc": "Japan"}]},{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "RUS","desc": "Russian"}]},{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "IND","desc": "Indian"}]},{"distance": 1.87,"age": "",languageCodes: [{"code": "RUS","desc": "Russian"}]}]};
const LanguageCodes = myObj.list.flatMap(obj => obj.languageCodes).filter((e, i, a) => a.findIndex(({ code, desc }) => code == e.code && desc == e.desc) == i);

console.log(LanguageCodes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Suggestion: language codes is an array so instead of `map` and `languageCodes[0]` we could use `flatMap` and languageCodes

Comment: Could you add your actual code for the suggestion @PanosK, I don't follow right now.

Comment: i mean this `myObj.list.flatMap(obj => obj.languageCodes).filter((e, i, a) => a.findIndex(({ code, desc }) => code == e.code && desc == e.desc) == i);`

Comment: That's not really an improvement at all @PanosK.

Comment: you will miss a unique language if its in index[1] with map thats what im trying to tell try it

Comment: I see @PanosK - sorry, I didn't realise that's what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```js
// const arr = inputObj.list;
const arr = [
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'RUS',
        'desc': 'Russian',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'RUS',
        'desc': 'Russian',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'IND',
        'desc': 'Indian',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'USA',
        'desc': 'American',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'AUS',
        'desc': 'Australian',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'JPN',
        'desc': 'Japan',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'RUS',
        'desc': 'Russian',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'IND',
        'desc': 'Indian',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    'distance': 1.87,
    'age': '',
    languageCodes: [
      {
        'code': 'RUS',
        'desc': 'Russian',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const uniqueLanguageCodes = arr.reduce((accum, current) => {
  current.languageCodes.forEach(codeObj => {
    if (!accum.some(accumElement => accumElement.code === codeObj.code)) {
      accum.push(codeObj);
    }
  });
  return accum;
}, []);

console.log(uniqueLanguageCodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the `languageCodes` to a single array using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Then, use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get unique languages

```js
const input = { list: [{ distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "RUS", desc: "Russian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "RUS", desc: "Russian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "IND", desc: "Indian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "USA", desc: "American" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "AUS", desc: "Australian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "JPN", desc: "Japan" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "RUS", desc: "Russian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "IND", desc: "Indian" }] }, { distance: 1.87, age: "", languageCodes: [{ code: "RUS", desc: "Russian" }] }] };
 
const merged = input.list.flatMap(a => a.languageCodes)
                         .reduce((acc, lang) => {
                            acc[lang.code] = lang;
                            return acc;
                         }, {})

const output = Object.values(merged)
console.log(output)
```